# ReferenceError: Cannot access Service' before initialization

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Im getting an error when i run a unit test with jasmine on angular8 app.
I have a service and inside this service im injecting another service

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class FirstService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configService: ConfigurationService) { }
```

when i do npm run test i always got an error:

> An error was thrown in afterAll   ReferenceError: Cannot access
>   'ConfigurationService' before initialization
>         at Module.ConfigurationService (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:1095:112)

Any help?

Comment: you are using ConfigurationService in FirstService. Hence you would have to create a mock for ConfigurationService

Comment: Please share the content of your `.spec.ts` file

Comment: i have this on my .spec.ts file:
`code describe('FirstService', () => {
  let configService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    configService = jasmine.createSpyObj('configService', ['getConfiguration']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [{ provide: ConfigurationService, useValue: configService }, FirstService]
    })
    configService.getConfiguration.and.returnValue({ serviceRestUrl: URL });
  });
  it('should be created', inject([FirstService], (service: FirstService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  })); `code

Comment: @faoc did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 13):

This can be a very misleading error message.

A circular dependency may be causing it, solve your circular dependencies!

You will not see a circular dependency warning when running 'npm run test', but you will get a warning when running 'npm run serve' or 'npm run build'.

Comment: helped me solving the issue

Comment: Helped me too. Thanks! Although I actually didn't get any warning when running 'ng build' or 'ng serve'.

Comment: Seriously saved my skin, thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 4):

You would need to provide a mock of `ConfigService` because it is a dependency of `FirstService`. The easiest way to do that is with a spy.

Something like:

```
let firstService: FirstServicec;
let configServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ConfigService>;

beforeEach(() => {
  const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ConfigService', ['getValue']);

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      FirstService,
      { provide: ConfigService, useValue: spy }
    ]
  });
  // Inject both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency
  configService = TestBed.get(ConfigService);
  configServiceSpy = TestBed.get(ValueService);
});
```

Then, you can consume the spy in the test like:

```
it('#getValue should return stubbed value from a spy', () => {
  const stubValue = 'stub value';
  configServiceSpy.getValue.and.returnValue(stubValue);

  expect(firstService.getValue())
    .toBe(stubValue, 'service returned stub value');
  expect(configServiceSpy.getValue.calls.count())
    .toBe(1, 'spy method was called once');
  expect(configServiceSpy.getValue.calls.mostRecent().returnValue)
    .toBe(stubValue);
});
```

For more information, check out this section of the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I think that there is some problem on FirstService. Because if i comment all the block code in firstservice.spec, i got exactly same error.

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ConfigurationService' before initialization
      at Module.ConfigurationService (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:1095:112)
(_karma_webpack_/src/app/shared/services/tags/first.service.ts:13:64)

Comment: @faoc are you loading `FirstService` in with `APP_INITIALIZER`? In any case, the module that contains `ConfigurationService` has not been loaded at the time you're trying to pass it into `FirstService`. Make sure the module containing your `ConfigurationService` is listed in the imports array of a module that is eagerly loaded.

Comment: I have both services with providedIn:'root';  On 'ng build' it runs perfectly without any issue, this problem just happens with 'ng test'

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your services/dependencies are imported exactly the same in both the class file and the spec file.

I have just had this with Angular 11 and come across a nasty gotcha. In my case, it was because the spec file and the component class imported a dependency service in the constructor in a different way.

In my spec file I had:

```
import { ExampleService } from '../../services';
```

But in my class file:

```
import { ExampleService } from '../../';
```

which resolved to the exact same file, but caused the same error. Making the imports the same fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a very stupid error. I was using abstract services and useClass stuff and had something like this in one file:

```
constructor(@Optional() private readonly baseService: BaseService) {
}
    
export abstract class BaseService {
    public abstract doSomething(): void;
}
```

Changing the order to

```
export abstract class BaseService {
    public abstract doSomething(): void;
}

constructor(@Optional() private readonly baseService: BaseService) {
}
```

solved the issue. OMG.