# Error during loading: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'UpdatesModalStore' before initialization

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm running into a weird issues with not being able to run angular tests. This is a root service with no circular dependencies. I've run `npx madge --circular --extensions ts ./` and confirmed there are none in this code. I've also confirmed when I comment out the `localStorage` getters and setters, the tests will run. Any ideas why I would be getting this error?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, take } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { UpdateNotificationStorageEnum } from '../components/updates-modal/updates-modal.component';
import { UpdateTile } from '../components/updates-modal/update-tile/update-tile.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UpdatesModalStore {
  private updateNotificationCountBS$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  private updatesOpenBS$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private updatesTilesBS$ = new BehaviorSubject<UpdateTile[]>([]);

  updateNotificationCount$ = this.updateNotificationCountBS$.asObservable();
  updatesOpen$ = this.updatesOpenBS$.asObservable();
  updatesTiles$ = this.updatesTilesBS$.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private snackbar: MatSnackBar
  ) { }

  setUpdateNotificationCount(count: number): void {
    this.updateNotificationCountBS$.next(count);
  }
  setUpdatesOpen(open: boolean): void {
    this.updatesOpenBS$.next(open);
  }

  initUpdatesModal(): void {
    const notificationCount = localStorage.getItem(UpdateNotificationStorageEnum.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_COUNT);
    if (!notificationCount) {
      this.setUpdateNotificationCount(1);
      localStorage.setItem(UpdateNotificationStorageEnum.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_COUNT, '1');
    } else {
      this.setUpdateNotificationCount(+notificationCount);
    }
  }

  toggleModal(): void {
    this.updatesOpen$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((open: boolean) => {
      const newOpenState = !open;
      this.setUpdatesOpen(newOpenState);
    });
  }

  setCurrentStep(steps: UpdateTile[]): void {
    this.updatesTilesBS$.next(steps);
  }

  setSmartSmartNotesEnabled(): void {
    localStorage.setItem(UpdateNotificationStorageEnum.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_STEP, '2');
    localStorage.setItem(UpdateNotificationStorageEnum.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_COUNT, '2');
    this.setUpdateNotificationCount(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: May be this answer will help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665922/referenceerror-cannot-access-service-before-initialization

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to provide an update here. I’ve found the issue is directly related to using localStorage within a forRoot  service. It has something to do with localStorage not being available at the the point the service is initialized. There are two solutions I have come up with without spending too much more time on this.

1. Move all local storage calls into the components using the service.
2. Set the emitDecoratorMetadata to false in the tsconfig.